# When I use Visual Studio 2013 and Qt5, the Intellisense give me wrong tips

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

When I use Visual Studio 2013 and Qt5,the Intellisense give me wrong tips such as "Error:Name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name".
The code can be compiled right.
how to fix it ?
thanks!

```
#include "gifacecomparegui.h"
giFaceCompareGUI::giFaceCompareGUI(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

Comment: im using the same and dont have those erros....

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by add a qt include path to "Tools->Option->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories->Include Directories", In my environment, the path is "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\include".

Comment: In new versions of visual studio `VC++ Directories` moved to project settings